# Can not resolve the OSGI Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.osgi.service.event

Tags: osgi, osgi-bundle

I am trying to run a OSGI bundle and I am always getting the error `Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.osgi.service.event`

I am using IntelliJ with OSGI plugin

There is my MANIFEST.MF file looks like

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-Activator: com.project.g.Publisher
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: pubs
Bundle-SymbolicName: pubs
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0
Bundle-ClassPath: lib/org.osgi.service.event-1.3.1.jar
Export-Package: com.project.g;uses:="org.osgi.framework";version=
 "1.0.0"
Import-Package: org.osgi.service.event,org.eclipse.osgi.util,org.apache.felix.gogo.command,
 org.osgi.framework,
 org.osgi.util.tracker
```

The Code ( from the example )

```
public class Publisher extends Thread implements BundleActivator {
    Hashtable time = new Hashtable();
    ServiceTracker tracker;

    @Override
    public void start(BundleContext bundleContext) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("started");
        tracker = new ServiceTracker(bundleContext, EventAdmin.class.getName(), null );
        tracker.open();
        start();

    }

    @Override
    public void stop(BundleContext bundleContext) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("stopped");
    }

    public void run() {
        while ( ! Thread.interrupted() ) try {
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            set(c,Calendar.MINUTE,"minutes");
            set(c,Calendar.HOUR,"hours");
            set(c,Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,"day");
            set(c,Calendar.MONTH,"month");
            set(c,Calendar.YEAR,"year");

            EventAdmin ea =
                    (EventAdmin) tracker.getService();
            if ( ea != null )
                ea.sendEvent(new Event("event/start", (Map<String, ?>) time));
            Thread.sleep(60000-c.get(Calendar.SECOND)*1000);
        } catch( InterruptedException e ) {
            return;
        }
    }

    void set(Calendar c, int field, String key ) {
        time.put( key, new Integer(c.get(field)) );
    }

}
```

and my project structure

[image]

[image]

What I am doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your bundle seems to be fine. You are only missing a provider of the package org.osgi.service.event at runtime. Try to install the bundle equinox Eventadmin or Felix Eventadmin.

Comment: Thanks for your response. do you mean in the Libraries? I have them in Lib and also in the main framework.

Comment: Not sure how this works in Intellij.  There must be a way to define the bundles to be installed in the OSGi Framework. There you have to add an Eventadmin bundle.

Comment: Thanks for your input. In eclipes, it works as you suggested. I love writing java in intelliJ though. In intellij OSGI support is really poor